# Find presence of a pair in 2d python list

Tags: python, list

I have a python list as follows:-

```
['cat', 'doc_1.txt'] 
['cat', 'doc_4.txt'] 
['dog', 'doc_5.txt'] 
['mouse', 'doc_6.txt'] 
['horse', 'doc_7.txt']
```

I need to quickly find out boolean answer to queries like

```
 "Does cat exist in doc_1.txt" answer = yes
 "Does mouse exist in doc_1.txt" answer = no
```

I have implemented it through nested loops which checks each document against each term and populate another list. It serves the purpose but thats very primitive way.

Comment: show a code atleast.

Comment: @Mehmaam : Showing nested loops solution would pollute the question with bad code ... The question asks for a better way of doing it, so showing the code isn't necessary to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Python keyword `in` to check if item `q` is in a list `L` with `q in L` which returns `True` if it is:

```
# I have a python list as follows:-
L = [
['cat', 'doc_1.txt'], 
['cat', 'doc_4.txt'], 
['dog', 'doc_5.txt'], 
['mouse', 'doc_6.txt'], 
['horse', 'doc_7.txt'],
] 
# I need to quickly find out boolean answer to queries like

q1 = "Does cat exist in doc_1.txt"   # answer = yes
q2 = "Does mouse exist in doc_1.txt" # answer = no

""" I have implemented it through nested loops which checks each 
document against each term and populate another list. It serves the 
purpose but thats very primitive way. """

def answer( q ):
    q = q.split()
    q = [q[1], q[4]]
    return "yes" if q in L else "no"

print(answer(q1)) # "yes"
print(answer(q2)) # "no"
```

Comment: I think you can edit your answer to _not include_ the full text & code of the original question. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Including the full text provides the context (and protects against substantial changes to the question). There is for example a contradiction in the question text between requesting a boolean value and mentioning yes/no as answer (instead of True/False).

Comment: The introductory text is now the actual answer to the question. The code just an add-on.

Comment: Noted. It's clearer now.

Answer (score -1):

If you have:

```
lst = [['cat', 'doc1.txt'], ['dog', 'doc2.txt']]
```

Then it's simple:

```
bools = [l[0] in open(l[1], 'r').read().split() for l in lst]
print(bools)
```

Comment: OP didn't say they wanted to _read files_.

Comment: @aneroid : it is not 100% clear that OP does not want to read files to answer the query ... so the above answer may be even the right one OP is looking for.